# Why does my pointer icon in CSS revert to the default icon after clicking on link for brief moment?

Tags: html, css

I have added my own icons on my website. The first is for default icon that will be used on website, while the second is for links. However after clicking on a link, when a new page loads, or when I click on an image, the default arrow icon appears for a brief moment.

I am using Google Chrome v.56 and Mozilla Firefox 49. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

CSS File:

```
body {
cursor: url(images/SnCPointer.png), auto;
}
a {
cursor: url(images/SnCLink.png), auto;
}
```

The website is: http://www.rglowimeeting.org/index.htm
The issue can be reproduced by holding down the 1st mouse button over the **Website under Construction** image

Comment: try using `a:focus` instead :) or `a:hover`

Comment: Sadly still not working :) I'll add the link of the website to the question details so it's clear what the problem is.

Comment: what you mean by other page, do you mean a page inside your website and have the same stylesheet?

Comment: when you go to the other page press `ctrl+F5` to reload the page with the new updated resources.

Comment: @Muhammad yes. There are multiple pages, but only one page is visible to users right now. However, on that 1st page as well as the other pages, the issue is reproducible. I have pressed ctrl+f5 multiple times, but the issue persists.

Comment: Try this `a:hover{ cursor: url(images/SnCLink.png), auto; }`

Comment: Have added that as well to the css file. Still the issue is there.